# How to measure conversion of login or registration page?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to optimize a kind of page that prompts the user to either login if the user already has an account or register otherwise.

I have setup events for when the user arrives to the page, clicks on one of several possible login buttons (username and password, Facebook account, Google account, etc) or clicks on the register button.

To measure the conversion I would like to see from all of those that arrive to the page but did not click the login buttons, what is the conversion rate of those that register.

Basically I need to measure Registered / (Landed - Logged in).

Is there a way to measure this with Google Analytics or do you recommend some other solution?﻿

Comment: I would recommend measuring the "registration successful" page. And you could create a funnel to see where the people went when they left the funnel (ie. logged in)

Comment: @rav79 I already measure the the conversion of registrations. What I cannot measure is how many of those that landed on that login/registration prompt page have not logged in but have  registered. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't perform calculations in analytics (as far as i know, anyway), but you could look into this https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2519989 and try to set up custom segments, maybe. Haven't tried that myself yet, so i can't really be sure.